# how to create folder view in pygtk inside main window

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to implement a folder viewer to view the structure of a specific path. and this folder view should look like a the tree widget in PyGtk , I used file dialog, but it doesn't expand down. Can anyone help? The figure below describes the idea of what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to browse filesystem folders? Or just some random type of hierarchy? And is this targeting Windows only, or all platforms?

Comment: @andlabs I am trying to browser filesystem folders on Windows platform.

Comment: GTK+ does not offer this facility out of the box. You will have to write it. You can look at the GtkFileChooserWidget source code for advice on how to do certain things. Note that the actual native-Windows control that provides a tree view of folders is something specific to the native Windows API and I'm not sure if you can use it alongside GTK+ or not...